# Task scheduler - task registration deleted by

Tags: windows, taskscheduler

I am using **task scheduler** to run a program weekly at 10am on a Friday for c.100 users in my company. 
The program launches a simple windows form, which is a survey users need to complete.

However, the **program is not running for c.50% of the users** (though not the same users each week).
I think perhaps the reason is that the task registration keeps being deleted (by User NT Authority/System), and then re-registered - see the picture below.

[image: Screenshot of Task Scheduler History]

I think this means that if the task hasnt been re-registered, then it wont run - hence the random set if users who get it.

Any suggestions on either:

1. What could be causing this **registration deletion** and how i can stop it
2. If there are any **other reasons why running the program might be failing** for some of my user group
3. **Workarounds to get the desired functionality** - launch a program weekly for many users

Answer (score 0):

I too get the same problem. It appears that its to do with the fact that the task sequence is delivered via group policy and the Action is Replace. So it is being deleted every time group policy is being applied. Also, it appears to stop running for some computers only when the random delay is triggered.
So if yours is group policy delivered you could try changing Replace to Update however then you could not use the option "remove this item when it is no longer applied".
If random delay is the issue then you could remove that option and try introducing a random delay as part of the command you are running. In my example I was running a powershell script so I just coded a random delay in the script.